# What is the mistake here?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-crawler, scrapy

These are my codes but it seems to be correct,but it doesn't work,please help

```
HEADER_XPATH = ['//h1[@class="story-body__h1"]//text()']    
AUTHOR_XPATH = ['//span[@class="byline__name"]//text()']   
PUBDATE_XPATH = ['//div/@data-datetime']  
WTAGS_XPATH = ['']   
CATEGORY_XPATH = ['//span[@rev="news|source""]//text()']    
TEXT = ['//div[@property="articleBody"]//p//text()']   
INTERLINKS = ['//div[@class="story-body__link"]//p//a/@href']  
DATE_FORMAT_STRING = '%Y-%m-%d'

class BBCSpider(Spider):
    name = "bbc"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
    sitemap_urls = [
        'http://Www.bbc.com/news/sitemap/',
        'http://www.bbc.com/news/technology/',
        'http://www.bbc.com/news/science_and_environment/']

    def parse_page(self, response):
        items = []
        item = ContentItems()
        item['title'] = process_singular_item(self, response, HEADER_XPATH, single=True)
        item['resource'] = urlparse(response.url).hostname
        item['author'] = process_array_item(self, response, AUTHOR_XPATH, single=False)
        item['pubdate'] = process_date_item(self, response, PUBDATE_XPATH, DATE_FORMAT_STRING, single=True)
        item['tags'] = process_array_item(self, response, TAGS_XPATH, single=False)
        item['category'] = process_array_item(self, response, CATEGORY_XPATH, single=False)
        item['article_text'] = process_article_text(self, response, TEXT)
        item['external_links'] = process_external_links(self, response, INTERLINKS, single=False)
        item['link'] = response.url
        items.append(item)
        return items
```

Comment: What is the problem? Maybe explain what the issue is ? Input? desire output? What you are doing?

Comment: the problem is that when I run my codes there is nothing happened. It doesn't go through the pages! and I think my mistakes are in the variables  @MooingRawr

Answer (score 0):

Your spider is just badly structured and because of that it does nothing.
The `scrapy.Spider` spider requires `start_urls` class attribute which should  contains list of urls that the spider will use to start the crawl, all of these urls will callback to class method `parse` which means it's required as well.

Your spider has `sitemap_urls` class attribute and it's not being used anywhere, also your spider has `parse_page` class method that is never used anywhere either.
So in short your spider should look something like this:

```
class BBCSpider(Spider):
    name = "bbc"
    allowed_domains = ["bbc.com"]
    start_urls = [
        'http://Www.bbc.com/news/sitemap/',
        'http://www.bbc.com/news/technology/',
        'http://www.bbc.com/news/science_and_environment/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # This is a page with all of the articles
        article_urls = # find article urls in the pages
        for url in article_urls:
            yield Request(url, self.parse_page)

    def parse_page(self, response):
        # This is an article page
        items = []
        item = ContentItems()
        # populate item
        return item
```

Comment: I really appreciate it

Comment: @nik great! If it resolved your question feel free to click the "accept question button" to the left of it.

Comment: ,for sure, I will. Would you please tell me in articles_urls what I have to provide as an example?(because I am dealing with lots of urls)

Comment: You need to figure out an xpath, something like this: `response.xpath("//a[contains(@class,'title-link')]/@href").extract()` finds some.